# Laravel: How to set & fetch custom header while redirecting to get method route url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 and trying to redirect to a url with custom headers. But some how I am not getting the header value in redirected page or we can say header value is not getting sent while redirecting.

I am using this code:

```
return redirect()->route('frontend.seller.signup')->header('referal_code', $referal_code);
```

and For fetch Header value I use below code but I not recieve header value

```
$referal_code = Request::header('referal_code');
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: When you redirect to another page $request object's value replaced by new values. In order to pass the $referalCode you need to put it in the Session.

Comment: Is there any other solution ?

Comment: You can put in the Session Variable like `Session::put('referalCode', $referalCode)`. Fetching thorugh `if(Session::has('referalCode')){$referalCode = Session::get('referalCode')}`. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you set headers for your response (even redirect is a response), headers are send to the client's browser.

The browser will process the response and redirect the page to the new URL and make a new request to server, so as you can figure out, your previous custom headers will not be available in the new request.

You can send any var using **with()** function to target url:

```
redirect()->route('frontend.seller.signup')->with('referral_code', $referral_code);
```

And get the variable in your target function using session:

```
$referral_code = session('referral_code');
```

By the way you can get the referrer in each request without setting any parameter in the referrer, if this is helpful in your case:

```
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
```